# how to loop a switch in eclipse

Tags: loops, switch-statement

I was trying to make a simple game where you would have to guess a number between 1 and 10 and I wanted to make it so it would repeat until you guessed the correct number. I was using a switch for this but I'm fairly new so I don't know necessarily how to loop a switch. I've looked at tutorials but wasn't getting anywhere with it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello traveler.. Please enter your.. your... name");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userName = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hello there " + userName);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the world of never ending lies. You can only leave if you solve my simple question.");
    System.out.println("What number between 1 and 10 do I like the most?");
    int numbs;
    numbs = in.nextInt(); // get numbers
    switch (numbs) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("This is not my favorite number.");
        System.out.println("Please try again traveler, though I shouldn't have to say it.");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("This traveler is indeed my favorite number."); // this is the right number
        System.out.println("Please try again traveler, though I shouldn't have to say it.");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Did I tell you about that time in France? WRONG AGAIN!");
        System.out.println("Please try again traveler, though I shouldn't have to say it.");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("This is definitely not it.");
        System.out.println("Please try again traveler, though I shouldn't have to say it.");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Wrong.");
        System.out.println("Please try again traveler, though I shouldn't have to say it.");
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Wrong again.");
        System.out.println("Please try again traveler, though I shouldn't have to say it.");
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println("Haha, you would think of this wouldn't you? W.r.O.n.G");
        System.out.println("Please try again traveler, though I shouldn't have to say it.");
        break;
    case 8:
        System.out.println("Not right at all");
        System.out.println("Please try again traveler, though I shouldn't have to say it.");
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("Who do you think that I are, some girl that you'd meet at a bar? WRONG.");
        System.out.println("Please try again traveler, though I shouldn't have to say it.");
        break;
    case 10:
        System.out.println("You are as naive as you are stupid. WRONG.");
        System.out.println("Please try again traveler, though I shouldn't have to say it.");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("That's not even a choice you fool.");
        System.out.println("Please try again traveler, though I shouldn't have to say it.");
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `while` loop on top of the `nextInt` line, with a condition that it will only exit the loop once the value is correct.

Have a look at the `while` loop statement.

As an example:

```
numbs = 0;
while(numbs != 2){
System.out.println("Guess the number");
numbs = in.nexInt();
//Switch statement here. When the loop gets to the top again, it'll see that number is 2, and hence will break from the loop.
}
```